# how to do calculations with multiple check boxes in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

for example i have 5 check boxes and these check boxes are names of products with different  prices which are constant and displayed in five text boxes when a certain check box is checked
and i also have 5 text boxes for the quantity which depends on the input of the user. now for example i only checked 2 check boxes and input their quantity let say product one = 100 and product 2 = to 200  and i input 2 for both of their quantity display the total amount in  only one text box. how can i code it because when i use the if else statement, it only calculate and display the price of one product while i have chosen or checked 2 products and when i used or in the if statement, when i only checked 2 check boxes and input their quantities, i get an error which is format string unhandle. This is my code:

```
If chkPopcorn.Checked = True Then
        quantity1 = Integer.Parse(txtQuantityPopcorn.Text)
        price1 = txtPricePopcorn.Text * quantity1
    ElseIf chkBurger.Checked = True Then
        quantity2 = Integer.Parse(txtQuantityBurger.Text)
        price2 = txtPriceBurger.Text * quantity2

    ElseIf chkSpaghetti.Checked = True Then

        quantity3 = Integer.Parse(txtQuantitySpaghetti.Text)
        price3 = txtPriceSpaghetti.Text * quantity3

    ElseIf chkHotdog.Checked = True Then

        quantity4 = Integer.Parse(txtQuantityHotdog.Text)
        price4 = txtPriceHotdog.Text * quantity4

    ElseIf chkCupcake.Checked = True Then

        quantity5 = Integer.Parse(txtQuantityCupcake.Text)
        price5 = txtPriceCupcake.Text * quantity5


    End If

End If
txtSales.Text = price1 + price2 + price3 + price4 + price5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple to fix, use 5 If statements in a row, instead of ElseIf

```
    If chkPopcorn.Checked = True Then
        quantity1 = Integer.Parse(txtQuantityPopcorn.Text)
        price1 = txtPricePopcorn.Text * quantity1
    End If
    If chkBurger.Checked = True Then
        quantity2 = Integer.Parse(txtQuantityBurger.Text)
        price2 = txtPriceBurger.Text * quantity2
    End If
    If chkSpaghetti.Checked = True Then
        quantity3 = Integer.Parse(txtQuantitySpaghetti.Text)
        price3 = txtPriceSpaghetti.Text * quantity3
    End If
    If chkHotdog.Checked = True Then
        quantity4 = Integer.Parse(txtQuantityHotdog.Text)
        price4 = txtPriceHotdog.Text * quantity4
    End If
    If chkCupcake.Checked = True Then

        quantity5 = Integer.Parse(txtQuantityCupcake.Text)
        price5 = txtPriceCupcake.Text * quantity5
    End If

    txtSales.Text = price1 + price2 + price3 + price4 + price5
End Sub
```